# Preloading SKTextures/SKTextureAtlas confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sktexture, sktextureatlas

I've read all of the posts on here regarding this topic and none of them seem to answer my question.

My question is when is a SKTexture/SKTextureAtlas loaded into memory?

From what I've read you need to keep strong a reference to any SKTexture or SKTextureAtlas loaded into memory with [SKTexture preloadTextures:
  withCompletionHandler:] so that it won't get released with ARC, Which makes sense to me because the object will get released at the end of the method when nobodies retaining it. What I don't understand is how a SKTexture with a strong pointer retaining it isn't loaded into memory, wouldn't this make [SKTexture preloadTextures: withCompletionHandler:] redundant and unnecessary since the textures already loaded in memory. I'm obviously missing something so any insight would be great.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SKTexture Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/) explains it like this:

> The texture data is loaded when:
>
> The size method on the texture object is called.
>
> Another method is called that requires the texture’s size, such as creating a new SKSpriteNode object that uses the texture object.
>
> One of the preload methods is called (See Preloading the Texture Data.)
>
> The texture data is prepared for rendering when:
>
> A sprite or particle that uses the texture is part of a node tree that is being rendered.
>
> Once the SKTexture object is ready for rendering, it stays ready until all strong references to the texture object are removed.